# How to use jQuery to increase the thymeleaf tag while getting the value in th:text

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I want to increase some thymeleaf tag by using jquery. According to F12, thymeleaf tag are increased, but its not working. How to fix it?

```
var part = "<div>\n" +
"  <span>Icon</span>\n" +
"  <span th:text='${commentList.username}'>username</span>\n" +
"</div>\n" +
"<div style=\"margin-left: 30px;\">\n" +
"  <span th:text='${commentList.content}'>content</span>\n" +
"</div>"
$(".commentDetails").html(part);
```

I want get the thymeleaf tag's value, but the value is not obtained

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't say much but with a lot of assumptions I am trying to answer.

on your html file, set your `part` variable as below

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/      

var part = "<div>\n" +
"  <span>Icon</span>\n" +
"  <span th:text='${commentList.username}'>username</span>\n" +
"</div>\n" +
"<div style=\"margin-left: 30px;\">\n" +
"  <span th:text='${commentList.content}'>content</span>\n" +
"</div>"        

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Now you can use your `jQuery` part

```
$(".commentDetails").html(part);
```

Comment: jQuery works,and tag th:text is added to the span but cannot get the value and I have passed the value of the commentList to the model in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `th:` part of the js. This is because even if you can insert values with thymeleaf syntax `${...}` if you use CDATA, thymeleaf won't process the th markers inside the html your js function provides, because they appear inside a String in a js function instead of being part of a tag in the html of your page.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/      

var part = "<div>\n" +
"  <span>Icon</span>\n" +
"  <span text='${commentList.username}'>username</span>\n" +
"</div>\n" +
"<div style=\"margin-left: 30px;\">\n" +
"  <span text='${commentList.content}'>content</span>\n" +
"</div>"        

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Still not working. It seems that the thymeleaf tag added by jQuery cannot be recognized?

Comment: @KeySky that is the case, and thats why you shouldn't include th: tags inside the html you are inserting.

Comment: What if I want to assign a value to the model after the ajax request is initiated, and then use the thymeleaf to get the data and  show the front end?

Comment: @KeySky if you fill the input with javascript after the ajax call and the input is inside the form that you submit, you will be able to get the data of this input in the controller with the rest of the form (assuming you created this form and the input you fill in js in a thymeleaf-wise manner).